# Can I include an 'industry dummy' in my Relative Weight analysis? Bootstrapping produces error message!

Tags: r, panel-data, bootstrap, multicollinearity, categorical-encoding

I am analyzing the impact of 7 different employee satisfaction variables(x1, x2,...,x7) on financial performance in 200 companies over 3 years. Since these 7 predictor variables are highly correlated and I want to estimate the relative importance of each of them, I am using the Relative Weights Analysis (RWA) and the R package "relaimpo".

My model looks like:

**financial performance = b1x1 + b2x2 + ... +b7x7 + b8firm_size + Year_dummy + Industry_dummy**

where:

- Year dummy = 3 years (one defined as reference group)
- Industry dummy = 9 industries (one defined as reference group)
- firm_size = log(total assets in each company)

## R code:

```
    #Calculate relative weights
        object <- lm(financial_performance~x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7 + log(Company_Assets) + Year_dummy + Industry_dummy, data = mydata)

        summary(object)

        RWA=calc.relimp(object, type = "lmg", always = c("Year_dummy", "Industry_dummy"))

        RWA

    #Perform Bootstrapping  
       boot <- boot.relimp(object, b = 100, type = "lmg", always = c("Year_dummy", "Industry_dummy"))

       booteval.relimp(boot)
```

## Error Message

> Error in calc.relimp.default.intern(cova, ...) : covg must be   a
>   positive definite covariance matrix   or a data matrix / data frame
>   with linearly independent columns.

Calculaing the relative weights (calc.relimp) works fine but when I perform **bootstrapping** (boot.relaimp) to determine the significance of the relative weight coefficients, I get the error message: 
**"Error in calc.relimp.default.intern(cova, ...) : covg must be a positive definite covariance matrix or a data matrix / data frame with linearly independent columns."**.

I guess this indicates that I have perfect multicollinearity in my model, but I do not understand why. My dummy variables are defined with one reference group to avoid the dummy variable trap. When removing the Industry_dummy or when decreasing the number of iterations to 100, the error disappears. There is no problem with the Year_dummy.

Does anyone of you know what the problem here could be and how to correct it?
I am new to RWA and bootstrapping so I appreciate all help and ideas!
Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you check if the bootstrap samples' design matrices are of full rank? It could be that one or more levels of *industry_dummy* are not represented in all.

Comment: Hi @Scortchi , thank you for yor comment. I am not sure how to properly test the rank of the bootstrap matrices, but I see your point in that all levels of the industry_dummy might not be present in all 1000 bootstrap samples. I just tested  to decrease the levels and the problem disappeared, so I think you are right. Would you recommend to cluster the industries somehow or how would you proceed? Once again thank you!